# How to show a triple represents all possible selections?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-writing

Let $Y=\{y_1, y_2, y_3,y_4,y_5\}$

Then, the choices of selecting 3 objects (repetitions allowed) from $Y$ can be represented by the triple $(y_{i_1},y_{i_2},y_{i_3})$ where $i_1 \le i_2 \le i_3$.

Is there a way to prove the that constructing the above triple with the given conditions results in all the choices of selecting 3 objects from $Y$ with repetition allowed?

In other words, how can I prove that the condition $i_1 \le i_2 \le i_3$ ensures that every possible selection is represented only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select three objects one after another (repetitions allowed), you'll end up with $(y_{j_1},y_{j_2},y_{j_3})$ where $j_k \in \{1,\dots,5\}$ for $k=1,2,3$.  Now, obviously each permutation of this $3$-tuple represents the same selection of objects, i.e. it doesn't depend on the order in which you selected them.  So you can as the "canonical" representation select the one where the indexes are ordered.